# using localization with label tag helper

Tags: c#, html, localization, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Ttextinput.cshtml

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer
@model string
<div class="form-group col-sm-6" >
  <label asp-for=@(localizer[@Model]) class=" control-label form-label "></label>
  <div class="">
    <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control form-textbox"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="text-danger "></span>
  </div>
</div>


"workflowformpage.cshtml"
using REU.ViewModelContracts
@model IWorkflowViewModel
<fieldset class=" form-group form">

        @if (Model.GetType().BaseType == typeof(AssignResultCollectionViewModel))
        {

            @Html.Partial("AssignResultCollection", Model);

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in Model.GetDisplayPropertyInfos())
            {
                @Html.Editor(propertyInfo.Name, null, Model.GetQualifiedPropertyName(propertyInfo.Name))
                //break;
            }
        }


    </fieldset>
```

I have a view displaying a form. And labels of textbox comes from model for which I used "  "and it works well and gives the value but now I want to implement localization with label, I tried something like this

```
<label asp-for="@localizer[@Model]" class=" control-label form-label ">
```

which doesn't give me values. Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

```
<label asp-for="@localizer[@Model]" class=" control-label form-label "> 
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asp-for` attribute is meant to contain the name of a C# property present in your page's model, and is not meant to contain a string to be displayed.

For example :

```cs
public class MyPageModel
{
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model MyPageModel
<label asp-for="Email"></label>
```

This will display the content of the `MyPageModel.Email` property that you pass in your controller. Therefore, it doesn't really make sense to pass a localized string in `asp-for`.

To complete your example, I'll assume that your `@Model` variable is a string. You could use this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<label>@Localizer[@Model]</label>
```

Comment: Hi, I am new in MVC6 and don't know much about it, But what I want is I have a model with different fields like textbox, dropdown, object reference etc and I have a view workflow which has  @Html.Editor(propertyInfo.Name, null, Model.GetQualifiedPropertyName(propertyInfo.Name)) in for loop and goes to another partial view called textinput in which I have @model string and to dispaly field I use <label asp-for=@(localizer[@Model]) class=" control-label form-label "></label> .